Monitor USB hub stoped working on Kubuntu 24.04
Today I disconnected all my USB devices first time after the system was reinstalled. When I reconnected them USB hub in my LG monitor stopped working. It is not even powering the connected devices (they were working a day ago).
System info:
ThinkPad X1 Extreme 2

I think somehow USB devices ended up stuck and suspended. I had this exact issue on 22.04 but I don't remember how I fixed it.
This is how I checked it.
cd /sys/bus/usb/devices
ls
1-0:1.0  1-11     1-1:1.1   1-1:1.2  1-14:1.0  1-2      1-2:1.1  1-8      1-8:1.1  1-8:1.3  1-9:1.0  3-0:1.0  usb1  usb3
1-1      1-1:1.0  1-11:1.0  1-14     1-14:1.1  1-2:1.0  1-2:1.2  1-8:1.0  1-8:1.2  1-9      2-0:1.0  4-0:1.0  usb2  usb4
for d in ./*/ ; do (cd "$d" && cat power/runtime_status); done

The output is:
suspended
active
active
suspended
suspended
unsupported
suspended
active
suspended
suspended
active
suspended
suspended
suspended
active
suspended
suspended
suspended
suspended
active
unsupported
suspended
suspended
suspended
active
active
active
active

My #1 attempt to fix the issue
https://askubuntu.com/questions/1140925/how-can-i-disable-usb-autosuspend-on-ubuntu-18-04#answer-1161074
After I had done this the command
cat /sys/module/usbcore/parameters/autosuspend

Return -1. The issue persists.
My #2 attempt to fix the issue
I tried to append on to this file for every device:
/sys/bus/usb/devices/XXX/control

However, even with root permissions it says permission denied.

I tried a bunch of other stuff but none of it worked. It is so frustrating. Why such a feature is enabled by default? It seems to always be happening to me after system reinstallation.
The funny thing is that I have a dual boot and the USB hub is also not working on Windows.
Can anyone help debugging and fixing this?

Nevermind guys, I did everything internet says and tried chat GPT help. Nothing fixes it.
I just won't use the monitor hub.
